# How does a YAML double exclamation point work in this i18n gem?

Tags: ruby, internationalization, yaml

I'm not using Rails and I haven't done any internationalization before, so I'm trying to understand how [this particular example](https://github.com/ai/r18n#filters) works but I'm a little bit stumped:

The `r18n-desktop` gem reads from a YAML file for translations. Pretty straightforward.

YAML file `en.yml`:

```
user:
  edit: Edit user
  name: User name is %1
  count: !!pl
    1: There is 1 user
    n: There are %1 users
log:
  signup: !!gender
    male: Он зарегистрировался
    female: Она зарегистрировалась
```

Test ruby code:

```
require 'r18n-desktop'
R18n.from_env('./localizations/')
R18n::Filters.add('gender') do |translation, config, user|
  puts translation
  puts config
  puts user
  translation[user.gender]
end
include R18n::Helpers

class Ayy
  attr_accessor :gender
end

girl = Ayy.new
girl.gender = :female

puts t.user.count(5)
puts t.log.signup girl
```

Output:

> There are 5 users
>
> localization-test.rb:13:in 
>   puts: can't convert R18n::Translation to Array (R18n::Translation#to_ary gives R18n::Untranslated) (TypeError)    from localization-test.rb:13:in puts'   from localization-test.rb:13:in '

Addenum: Looks like the error is in `puts` rather than the "translation". The actual result of a translation is `log.signup[]` though so the gender isn't getting through.

#### What is `t.log.signup()` expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget to set a filter for `!!gender` custom type.

R18n has only few built-in filter — like `!!pl`. Gender filter is not built-in, you need to define it manually.

[R18n Filter docs](https://github.com/ai/r18n#filters) already contains simple filter example for gender:

```
R18n::Filters.add('gender') do |translation, config, user|
  translation[user.gender]
end
```